# File Upload richfaces IndexOutOfBoundsException Buffer.checkBounds

Tags: java, jsf, unix, file-upload, richfaces

Good day,

I´m using richfaces component to upload files (FileUpload[FileUpload](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf?c=fileUpload)). The problem it´s give me an error, only when the software is use on unix server. When i test in my machine, on eclipse, the "add" of files, works.

```
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] 
JSF1053: (Listener: org.richfaces.component.FileUploadPhaselistener.beforePhase(), Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1,  View ID: ) Exception thrown during phase-listener execution: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle]
java.nio.Buffer.checkBounds(Buffer.java:530)
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:215)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.readMessage(AjpAprProcessor.java:1174)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.receive(AjpAprProcessor.java:1099)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AjpAprProcessor.java:1239)
org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:428)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:332)
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:420)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:364)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:162)
org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.fillBuffer(MultipartRequest.java:415)
org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.initialize(MultipartRequest.java:583)
org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:616)
org.richfaces.component.FileUploadPhaselistener.beforePhase(FileUploadPhaselistener.java:63)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:214)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:96)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:102)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)

.......
.......
.......

org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:419)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:402)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2036)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

No causeBy...
Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post you listener method?

Comment: Update: It works if i take the ssl autentication (https) and use simple http...
Any suggestion?

Comment: My listener is from [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/apidoc/org/richfaces/component/FileUploadPhaselistener.html) richfaces-ui :|